# Magento2 update layout according to attribute set

Tags: magento-2.1

I have to create new layout on product view page using xml on the bases of product attribute set......

Trying this but no luck: layout/catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_10.xml

Any idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom module, you can create a plugin for the `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View` class's `initProductLayout` method.

Your plugin class would be something like this:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;

class View
{
    public function beforeInitProductLayout(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject,
        ResultPage $resultPage, Product $product, $params = null
    ) {
        $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(
          ['attribute_set_id' => $product->getAttributeSetId()]
        );

        return [$resultPage, $product, $params];
    }
}
```

Then `catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_10.xml` will be included for products that use attribute set 10.